# File upload option is appearing serialized in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, file-upload

I just updated a Magento store to 1.9.2 and now something strange is happen.

I have plugin that is recalculate the price when a product is added to the cart. The code triggers with an event observer (sales_quote_add_item)

In the product I have the possibility to upload a file. the problem is in the cart. It worked in Mage 1.9.1. but for some reason, the file is not appearing as a link, but as a serialized object in the cart.

It used to be something like: logo_green.jpg (600px x 600px)

It's now: {s:4:"type";s:9:"image/png";s:5:"title";s:14:"logo_green.png";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/l/o/355f0bb9f96e6b8ae3cb6d05b5299803.png";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/l/o/355f0bb9f96e6b8ae3cb6d05b5299803.png";s:8:"fullpath";s:137:"/Users/roywulms/Documents/Projecten/karakterprints/karakterprints/new/media/custom_options/quote/l/o/355f0bb9f96e6b8ae3cb6d05b5299803.png";s:4:"size";s:5:"26160";s:5:"width";i:600;s:6:"height";i:600;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"355f0bb9f96e6b8ae3cb";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";N;s:3:"key";s:20:"355f0bb9f96e6b8ae3cb";}}}

When I remove my plugin, it's working again.

This my observer code:

```
public function changingPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $quote_item->getProduct();
    $quantity = ($product->getQty()) ? $product->getQty() : $quote_item->getQty();
    $options = $this->getProductOptions($quote_item);
    if(sizeof($options) > 0)
    {
        $basePrice = $product->getPrice();
        foreach($options as $option)
        {
          $basePrice = ($basePrice + $option['price']);

            if($option['option_type'] == 'height')
                $heightVal =  $option['value'];
            if($option['option_type'] == 'width')
                $widthVal =  $option['value'];
        }


        $dimensionsPrice =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getData('dimension_price');

        if(isset($heightVal) && isset($widthVal)){
          $meter = $basePrice + ($widthVal * $heightVal)*$dimensionsPrice;
          $new_price = $meter*$quantity;
          $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        }
    }
 }

public function getProductOptions(&$item)
{
  $options = array();

  if ($optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids')) {
    $options = array();
    foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
      if ($option = $item->getProduct()->getOptionById($optionId)) {

        $quoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());

        $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
        ->setOption($option)
        ->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);

        $options[] = array(
          'label' => $option->getTitle(),
          'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue(unserialize($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
            'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
            'price'=> $group->getOptionPrice($quoteItemOption->getValue(),0),
            'option_id' => $option->getId(),
            'option_type' => $option->getType(),
            'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView()
            );
        }
      }
    }
    if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
      $options = array_merge($options, unserialize($addOptions->getValue()));
    }
    return $options;
  }
}
```

How the code is triggered in config.xml:

```
 <events>
    <sales_quote_add_item>
        <observers>
           <Roywulms_Dimensioncalculator_Model_Observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>Roywulms_Dimensioncalculator_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>changingPrice</method>
           </Roywulms_Dimensioncalculator_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
   </sales_quote_add_item>
</events>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found the solution:

In the getProductOptions() function, change

```
$group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                      ->setOption($option)
                      ->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);
```

to

```
$group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                    ->setOption($option)
                    ->setConfigurationItem($item)
                    ->setConfigurationItemOption($itemOption);
```